How to make sure dconf (or gsettings) and <guix>/dconf-editor use the same backend database
Disclaimer: I'm running Guix package manager as a user on Ubuntu 22.04.4. That is most likely part of the problem: Guix uses non traditional paths for packages and sets symlinks and various search-path directories (such as PATH, XDG_CONFIG_HOME, etc.) to make them accessible to the apps.

My /usr/bin/dconf and /usr/bin/gsettings installed by apt read and write my "~/.config/dconf/user" database (GVariant).
My guix shell dconf-editor -- dconf-editor provided by Guix package manager reads and writes my "~/.config/glib-2.0/settings/keyfile" database (.ini-style text file).

More over, other apps (emacs, firefox) installed through Guix read their settings (e.g. cursor-theme) from "~/.config/glib-2.0/settings/keyfile"
So when I modify a value in dconf-editor, it is persisted (i.e., I can see the same value in dconf-editor after a reboot), but the modification is not visible in dconf CLI.
Similary, when I modify a value in dconf or gsettings, it is persisted and can be read through dconf or gsettings, but not visible in dconf-editor, and has no effect on my Firefox.

Which file is the canonical one?
How do I make sure all my applications access the same gsettings configuration?

My dconf profile:
$ ls /etc/dconf/profile/
ibus
$ cat /etc/dconf/profile/ibus
user-db:user
system-db:ibus

dconf-service environment:
$ tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/2423/environ
HOME=/home/necto
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LOGNAME=necto
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID=2423
USER=necto
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
MOZ_DISABLE_WAYLAND_PROXY=1
WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-1
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=sway
MANAGERPID=2102
INVOCATION_ID=f3d9238a3ad04b38aa6f719eebf5a037
JOURNAL_STREAM=8:39075

EDIT: Initially I thought dconf-editor operates on /run/user/1000/dconf/user but I found out that it is not a real DConf DB as it contains only 2 zero bytes.
